# Get myself out of the MySQL reporting loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database which has 10 tables in it.  The database structure is simple and there are on average 25 columns per table.  This means that there are many, many ways of "slicing and dicing" the data - no problem, I just use the command line to pull out what is needed.

The problem is that the main user of the database comes to me, says what she wants and I run the query.  As she is very competent, there is no reason why (with a bit of training) she couldn't query (SELECT only) the data herself using a suitable tool.  That would get me out of the reporting loop for straight-forward queries and make reporting more efficient.

Does anyone know of a tool that could be used here?  Ideally PHP-based.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpmyadmin http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

This is the tool used by the majority of web hosting companies. You can make her a user with only select privileges and she can run all the queries she wants and even save them to CSV for easy importing.

If a PHP/web solution isn't required you could use MySQL Workbench
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Thanks sreimer.  I was under the impression that phpmyadmin shouldn't be used in a production environment, see http://serverfault.com/questions/68264/would-you-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-production-web-server  Also I was hoping for (apologies, I should have said) something a bit less industrial.

Comment: Keep it internal (no public access)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Access 2003 is the simplest tool I've used for this.

I wouldn't pay for it but if you already have it installed on your machines you should give it a go.

You need an ODBC driver to the database, then 'link' to the tables from Access.  Then you can use the query designer without the need to learn SQL.

The main benefit is super-fast turnaround and a nice UI, drawbacks are stability and scalability so make sure she keeps a backup of her Access DB if it starts to have 'useful' (i.e. eventually critical) queries in it.  Or suggest she just create a new db and link the tables each time she needs to dip into the data.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks.  You've highlighted a very good concern over "useful" queries.  I'll give it some thought.